# securing controller added to jasig cas 3.5.2

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas, spring-security-cas

I have been tasked with adding password change functionality to our CAS Server, but am new to CAS as well as Spring.  I have successfully added a multi action controller to the overlay, but I am at a loss as to how to secure the views and require the user to be authenticated before viewing the pages.  As of now, this is what I have added to the CAS overlay project:

web.xml

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pm/change/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cas</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pm/change/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

cas-servlet.xml

```
<property name="mappings">
  <props>
    ...
    <prop key="/pm/change/*">passwordChangeController</prop>
  </props>
</property>

<bean id="passwordChangeController" class="...PasswordChangeController"
        p:passwordChangeView="default/ui/pmPasswordChangeView"
        p:passwordChangeSuccessView="default/ui/pmPasswordChangeSuccessView"
        />
```

I believe I am missing mappings in securityContext.xml, but everything I have tried there has ended in endless redirect loops, or simply access denied messages in all cases.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you